# puppet-vcsrepo module, retry checkout if a failure occurs

Tags: svn, puppet

I have an issue with svn checkout because of an svn server issue.

Is it possible somehow to clean-up -> update a repository if I get error during svn checkout?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the [official VCS module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo/), I believe you can use the `force => 'true`option to ensure that the content is always correct, which will add the `--force` tag to the svn command.

**However**, using force is destructive so I'd double check you're not removing any files you need. It'll also need snv version > 1.3 from a quick look at the documentation.